# angular 5 auth guard navigation

Tags: angular, auth-guard

My application works fine without auth guard when I try to implement the security I got navigation problem.
The problem is auth guard is passing the condition(tested using console.log). The url is changing to /prpage butviewport still remains in the same place as I am seeing the content of /formpage and not navigating to that page(/prpage) properly.

**app-router.module.ts**

```
{
   path: 'prpage', 
   component: PrPageComponent,
   canActivate: [AuthGuard] 
 }
```

**auth.guard.ts**

```
canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
   if (this.userService.id) {
    console.log("pass");
      return true;
    }
this.router.navigate(['/register'], { relativeTo: this.route });
      console.log("fail");
      return false;
  }
}
```

**form.component.ts**

```
if(response.name!==null){
 this.router.navigate(['/prpage'], { relativeTo: this.route });
}
```

Comment: Few questions `if(response.name!==null){`
 `this.router.navigate(['/prpage'], { relativeTo: this.route });`
`}` how is this condition triggered ?
If this is the navigating trigger whether the control reaches inside this if ?

Comment: If condition check's API response is not null then navigate should take place. I am worried that url path is changing but not the viewport.

Comment: Can you change path:’/prpage’ first and also paste the code for your router registration in app module

Comment: Yes register already there in router it has all list of router required. Just now i came across that while i am putting auth guard the url changing but not loading the page view. When i remove the auth guard and work the url is changing but not loading the viewport when i refresh the page it loads that page properly. I am facing problem in navigation to the viewport.

Comment: do you mind creating the plunkr or sharing the files i would like to run and debug locally

Comment: sorry i can't do that.But can give you partial dummy code.